# About apartment threading models

Tags: multithreading, com, apartments

I have a few questions about Apartments:

1. Was this model introduced for COM purposes only?
2. Can you point to good resources about them?
3. From a thread safety standpoint what does it mean that a component supports STA or MTA model?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe I can help with your second question. In this topic I have the following bookmarks in my  browser:

1. [Understanding and Using COM Threading Models](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809971.aspx)
2. [Understanding COM Apartments, Part I](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/apts/article.php/c5529)
3. [Understanding COM Apartments, Part II](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/apts/article.php/c5533)

Comment: After reading number 2 it seems that this model was probably introduced for COM purposes. Also the article explains the implications of the apartment mode.